# How to send dynamic values to mail function in laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel

i have this code for sending mail from Laravel.This code is perfectly running well.

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.accept', array(), function($message) {
                        $message->to('abc@gmail.com', 'abc')->subject('This is a demo!');
                    });
```

But i can only be able to send the message using hardcode values such as abc@gmail.com.

Whenever I try this.

```
 Mail::send('emails.auth.accept', array(), function($message) {
                        $message->to($user, $name)->subject('This is a demo!');
                    });
```

Above code is giving me error : Undefined variable: user. That means it is not accepting dynamic values.
help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
//see use statement
Mail::send('emails.auth.accept', array(), function($message) use($user, $anything) {
  $message->to('abc@gmail.com', 'abc')->subject('This is a demo!');
});
```

The problem with your code is that the anonymous function has its own context in which your data is not available. That's why you need to make use of `use` statement to pass data from context of your method to anonymous function.

For further information you can check this link http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to use. Here is a link that provides an example.

http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8264